# Do I need to restart my resque after changing code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

I'm using [resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque) to do some background processing for jobs in my Rails app. If I modify some of the logic in my Rails app around the background processing, do I need to restart resque in order for the changes to be picked up?

I thought not, but I was having problems until I did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends.

In development mode, you will not need to restart your workers.

However, in production mode, restarting your workers is essential since code caching is performed for performance.

You can use the cool gem "god" to monitor your workers in your production environment

Comment: if you can read this, this must still be relevant in 2015, yeah?